# Unable to install ESP-IDF with Eclipse IDE on Windows 10

Tags: eclipse-plugin, esp-idf

Having spent two whole days on the same issue I am at my wits end.
Have installed all pre-requisites and Windows environment variables for Python, GIT and Java all of which are working but for some unkown reason when trying to install via the Espressif ESP-IDF Tools manager I still receive WARNING: Git was not found as well as the below FileNotFoundError...?
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v5.0.1\tools\idf.py\tools/tools.json'
ErrorError

Windows path for **"User variables for deans"** incldues the following:
C:\Users\deans\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
D:\Java\jdk-20\bin
C:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe
C:\Espressif\tools\idf-git\2.39.2\mingw64\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Users\deans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
**System Variables**
`C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Espressif\ESP-IDF Tools\mconf-idf
C:\Program Files\Espressif\ESP-IDF Tools\tools\bin
D:\Java\jdk-20\bin
C:\Espressif\tools\idf-python\3.11.2\python.exe
C:\Espressif\tools\idf-git\2.39.2\mingw64\bin\git.exe
C:\Users\deans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Program Files\CMake\bin

Eclipse IDE Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
**[ESP-IDF Tools installation dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMkuZ.png)**
Python Version: Have tried both 3.7-32 as well as 3.11

Result of trying to install pasted below.

Installing tools...
This can take a while. Please be patient.
Executing C:\Users\deans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py install all
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1855, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1851, in main
action_func(args)
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1406, in action_install
tools_info = load_tools_info()
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 937, in load_tools_info
with open(tool_versions_file_name, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v5.0.1\tools\idf.py\tools/tools.json'
ErrorError

Executing C:\Users\deans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py install-python-env
WARNING: Git was not found
WARNING: Is it not possible to determine the IDF version: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v5.0.1\tools\idf.py\components\esp_common\include\esp_idf_version.h'
ERROR: IDF version cannot be determined
ErrorError

Executing C:\Users\deans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py export --format=key-value
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1855, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1851, in main
action_func(args)
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 1165, in action_export
tools_info = load_tools_info()
File "D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v4.3.5\tools\idf_tools.py", line 937, in load_tools_info
with open(tool_versions_file_name, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v5.0.1\tools\idf.py\tools/tools.json'

Comment: Please format code, error messages, etc. as _Code Sample_ to keep line breaks and which also does not require escaping via '\'.

Comment: The system path and the PATH in the IDE env is different, initially while installation of tools the espressif plugin may take into account the system path variables but after the installation the IDE is totally independent of PATH variables in the system. The guys are pretty active on their github issues you can open new issues their to get the dev teamd direct support as well
https://github.com/espressif/idf-eclipse-plugin/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  It appears that the path to locate `idf.py` is modified by invoking the `idf_tools.py` application.

The `idf_tools.py` application appends `\tools\idf.py` to the path whenever it is invoked. So in order for Windows to find `idf.py` you must enter the path as for example `D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v5.0.1\` and when invoked the actual path will become `D:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf-v5.0.1\tools\idf.py`, which is anoying to say the least.

I am sure there must be a valid reason why anyone would create an application that modifes the path as a path should in my opinion be static and remain as a path to the executable only.